# How to calculate the data contained in the variable through array

Tags: javascript

I wrote a web page
Calculate the sum and average score of each student's Chinese, English, and mathematics, as well as the average score of the whole class of Chinese, English, and mathematics.
I successfully obtained the value of each variable by using the array method, but I don't know how to calculate the value obtained by the array?

I hope I can ask for help and advice
thank you all

My code:

```js
function a1() {
  Array[0]=parseInt(document.getElementById('chi').value);
  Array[0]=parseInt(document.getElementById('math').value);
  Array[0]=parseInt(document.getElementById('eng').value);
}
```

````html
<style>
p{
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 18px;
}
</style>
<table border="1" style="width: 800px;">
  <tr>
    <td style="height: 50px; width: 150px;"><p>number</p></td>
    <td style="height: 50px; width: 150px;"> <p>chinese</p></td>
    <td style="height: 50px; width: 150px;"><p>english</p></td>
    <td style="height: 50px; width: 150px;"> <p>math/p></td>
    <td style="height: 50px; width: 150px;"> <p>total</p></td>
    <td style="height: 50px; width: 150px;"> <p>avg</p></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td style="height: 50px; width: 150px;"> <p>1</p></td>
     <td style="height: 50px; width: 150px;"><input type="text" value="" style="height: 50px ;width: 150px;" id="chi"></td>
      <td style="height: 50px; width: 150px;"><input type="text" value="" style="height: 50px ;width: 150px;" id="eng"></td>
      <td style="height: 50px; width: 150px;"><input type="text" value="" style="height: 50px ;width: 150px;" id="math"></td>
      <td style="height: 50px; width: 150px;"><input type="text" value="" style="height: 50px ;width: 150px;" id="t1"></td>
      <td style="height: 50px;width: 150px;"><input type="text" value="" style="height: 50px ;width: 150px;" id="a1"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td style="height: 50px; width: 150px;"> <p>2</p></td>
       <td style="height: 50px; width: 150px;"><input type="text" value="" style="height: 50px ;width: 150px;" id="chi"></td>
       <td style="height: 50px; width: 150px;"><input type="text" value="" style="height: 50px ;width: 150px;" id="eng"></td>
       <td style="height: 50px; width: 150px;"><input type="text" value="" style="height: 50px ;width: 150px;" id="math"></td>
       <td style="height: 50px; width: 150px;"><input type="text" value="" style="height: 50px ;width: 150px;" id="t2"></td>
       <td style="height: 50px;width: 150px;"><input type="text" value="" style="height: 50px ;width: 150px;" id="a2"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="height: 50px; width: 150px;"> <p>.......</p></td>
      <td style="height: 50px; width: 150px;"> <p>.......</p></td>
      <td style="height: 50px; width: 150px;"> <p>.......</p></td>
      <td style="height: 50px; width: 150px;"> <p>.......</p></td>
      <td style="height: 50px; width: 150px;"> <p>.......</p></td>
      <td style="height: 50px; width: 150px;"> <p>.......</p></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="height: 50px; width: 150px;"> <p>50</p></td>
      <td style="height: 50px; width: 150px;"><input type="text" value="" style="height: 50px ;width: 150px;" id="chi"></td>
      <td style="height: 50px; width: 150px;"><input type="text" value="" style="height: 50px ;width: 150px;" id="eng"></td>
      <td style="height: 50px; width: 150px;"><input type="text" value="" style="height: 50px ;width: 150px;" id="math"></td>
      <td style="height: 50px; width: 150px;"><input type="text" value="" style="height: 50px ;width: 150px;" id="t3"></td>
      <td style="height: 50px;width: 150px;"><input type="text" value="" style="height: 50px ;width: 150px;" id="a3"></td>
     </tr>
                     <tr>
                        <td style="height: 50px;"><p>avg</p></td>
                        <td style="height: 50px;"><input type="text" value="" style="height: 50px ;width: 150px;" id="u1"></td>
                        <td style="height: 50px;"><input type="text" value="" style="height: 50px ;width: 150px;" id="u2"></td>
                        <td style="height: 50px;"><input type="text" value="" style="height: 50px ;width: 150px;" id="u3"></td>
                        <td style="height: 50px;"><input type="text" value="" style="height: 50px ;width: 150px;" id="u7"></td>
                        <td style="height: 50px;"></td>
                         </tr>
                     </table>
                     <input type="button" value="ok" onclick="a1()">
```
````

Comment: Please note that element `id`s must be unique

Comment: `I successfully obtained the value of each variable by using the array method` ... is actually an unsuccessful attempt as it appears in your question's body.

Comment: @Jason : Hey Jason, I have initiated a correct approach to write the code in your example. Just go through it and try to understand what I have done to get avg and total for one student. However you need to repeat the process for the rest of the students. That is kind of Home work for you, if I am allowed to say that. Just kiddling. Give it a shot. Do rate and accept the answer if you find some help." I have set the initial sail, you need to control the rest of the journey"

Comment: I understand, thank you very much for your assistance

Comment: Ok, no problem
Thank you again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you should not use `id` every where, instead you must use `class`.

Then either fetch them using `document.getElementsByClassName("className")` or `document.querySelectorAll(".className")`. In both the scenarios you will be returned the array. You will need to loop over the array to perform your operations.

**UPDATE:** I have updated your HTML to use `class` attribute where ever required. Also used this in a form for better user experience so that only when the values marks are provided form is submitted.

I am providing a demo for you to  calculate total and avg of one student. You need to build on top of this logic dynamically for the rest of the students. Give it a shot.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  const form = document.querySelector(".main-form");

  form.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const student1Marks = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".std1"));
    //console.log(student1Marks);
    total1 = student1Marks.reduce((total, studentInput) => {
      console.log(studentInput.value);
      total = total + parseInt(studentInput.value);
      return total;
    }, 0);

    document.querySelector(".t1").value = total1;
    document.querySelector(".a1").value = parseInt(total1 / 3); // provide your own avg logic
  });
});
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
        <title>JS Bin</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <form class="main-form">
          <table border="1" style="width: 800px">
            <tr>
              <td style="height: 50px; width: 150px"><p>number</p></td>
              <td style="height: 50px; width: 150px"><p>chinese</p></td>
              <td style="height: 50px; width: 150px"><p>english</p></td>
              <td style="height: 50px; width: 150px"><p>math</p></td>
              <td style="height: 50px; width: 150px"><p>total</p></td>
              <td style="height: 50px; width: 150px"><p>avg</p></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td style="height: 50px; width: 150px"><p>1</p></td>
              <td style="height: 50px; width: 150px">
                <input
                  type="text"
                  value=""
                  style="height: 50px; width: 150px"
                  class="chi std1"
                  required
                />
              </td>
              <td style="height: 50px; width: 150px">
                <input
                  type="text"
                  value=""
                  style="height: 50px; width: 150px"
                  class="eng std1"
                  required
                />
              </td>
              <td style="height: 50px; width: 150px">
                <input
                  type="text"
                  value=""
                  style="height: 50px; width: 150px"
                  class="math std1"
                  required
                />
              </td>
              <td style="height: 50px; width: 150px">
                <input
                  type="text"
                  value=""
                  style="height: 50px; width: 150px"
                  class="t1"
                  readonly
                />
              </td>
              <td style="height: 50px; width: 150px">
                <input
                  type="text"
                  value=""
                  style="height: 50px; width: 150px"
                  class="a1"
                  readonly
                />
              </td>
            </tr>
            <!--             
              <tr>
                <td style="height: 50px; width: 150px"><p>2</p></td>
                <td style="height: 50px; width: 150px">
                  <input
                    type="text"
                    value=""
                    style="height: 50px; width: 150px"
                    class="chi std2"
                    required
                  />
                </td>
                <td style="height: 50px; width: 150px">
                  <input
                    type="text"
                    value=""
                    style="height: 50px; width: 150px"
                    class="eng std2"
                    required
                  />
                </td>
                <td style="height: 50px; width: 150px">
                  <input
                    type="text"
                    value=""
                    style="height: 50px; width: 150px"
                    class="math std2"
                    required
                  />
                </td>
                <td style="height: 50px; width: 150px">
                  <input
                    type="text"
                    value=""
                    style="height: 50px; width: 150px"
                    class="t2"
                    readonly
                  />
                </td>
                <td style="height: 50px; width: 150px">
                  <input
                    type="text"
                    value=""
                    style="height: 50px; width: 150px"
                    class="a2"
                    readonly
                  />
                </td>
              </tr>

              <tr>
                <td style="height: 50px; width: 150px"><p>3</p></td>
                <td style="height: 50px; width: 150px">
                  <input
                    type="text"
                    value=""
                    style="height: 50px; width: 150px"
                    class="chi std3"
                    required
                  />
                </td>
                <td style="height: 50px; width: 150px">
                  <input
                    type="text"
                    value=""
                    style="height: 50px; width: 150px"
                    class="eng std3"
                    required
                  />
                </td>
                <td style="height: 50px; width: 150px">
                  <input
                    type="text"
                    value=""
                    style="height: 50px; width: 150px"
                    class="math std3"
                    required
                  />
                </td>
                <td style="height: 50px; width: 150px">
                  <input
                    type="text"
                    value=""
                    style="height: 50px; width: 150px"
                    class="t3"
                    readonly
                  />
                </td>
                <td style="height: 50px; width: 150px">
                  <input
                    type="text"
                    value=""
                    style="height: 50px; width: 150px"
                    class="a3"
                    readonly
                  />
                </td>
              </tr>
              -->
          </table>
          <input type="submit" />
        </form>
      </body>
    </html>


  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var sumofval = 0;
itemsArray = [10,5,7];
for( var i = 0; i < itemsArray.length; i++ ){
    sumofval += parseInt( itemsArray[i]); 
}

var avg = sumofval/itemsArray.length;
console.log(avg);
```

please check out the above code, here I'm adding the iterated array value to the `sumofval` and in `avg` variable storing the average value from the iterated divided by the length of the array